# How does this do block work?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I just started learning haskell a few weeks ago and I saw this:

```
moves = do
    f <- [(+), subtract]
    g <- [(+), subtract]
    (x, y) <- [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
    [f x *** g y]
```

I haven't seen a `do` block ending in a `list` before, it was part of a solution to the knights tour problem.. Can somebody explain how it works?

Comment: This code is equivalent to `moves = [f x *** g y | f <- [(+), subtract],  g <- [(+), subtract], (x, y) <- [(1, 2), (2, 1)]]`

Comment: In the list monad `[x] = return x`.

Answer (score 6):

You have to desugar the notation. First start by writing down the types:

```
import Control.Arrow

moves :: [(Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer)]
moves = do
    f <- [(+), subtract]
    g <- [(+), subtract]
    (x, y) <- [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
    [f x *** g y]
```

So we are in the `[]` (list) monad.

Lookup the definition of [Monad []](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#fmap):

```
instance  Monad []  where
    m >>= k             = foldr ((++) . k) [] m
    m >> k              = foldr ((++) . (\ _ -> k)) [] m
    return x            = [x]
```

And translate the do notation to bind and return:

```
moves =
    [(+), subtract] >>= \f ->
    [(+), subtract] >>= \g ->
    [(1, 2), (2, 1)] >>= \(x,y) ->
    [f x *** g y]
```

Then, finally, rewrite the binds in terms of their definitions:

By `return` on list

```
moves =
    [(+), subtract] >>= \f ->
    [(+), subtract] >>= \g ->
    [(1, 2), (2, 1)] >>= \(x,y) ->
    return (f x *** g y)
```

Definition of >>=

```
moves =
    foldr ((++) . (\f ->

            [(+), subtract] >>= \g ->
            [(1, 2), (2, 1)] >>= \(x,y) ->
            return (f x *** g y)

            )) [] [(+), subtract]
```

Definition of >>=

```
moves =
    foldr ((++) . (\f ->
        foldr ((++) . (\g ->
                [(1, 2), (2, 1)] >>= \(x,y) ->
                return (f x *** g y))
                ) [] [(+), subtract]
            )) [] [(+), subtract]
```

Definition of >>=

```
moves =
    foldr ((++) . (\f ->
        foldr ((++) . (\g ->
            foldr ((++) . (\(x,y) -> return (f x *** g y))
                    ) [] [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
                )) [] [(+), subtract]
            )) [] [(+), subtract]
```

Undo the return:

```
moves =
    foldr ((++) . (\f ->
        foldr ((++) . (\g ->
            foldr ((++) . (\(x,y) -> [f x *** g y])
                    ) [] [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
                )) [] [(+), subtract]
            )) [] [(+), subtract]
```

So you see its a nested fold over two element lists. 
Unfolding the folds is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: I already know what's going on in a list-monad do-comprehension, but I find the desugared version with `foldr` impossible to follow. I don't see how it's supposed to help someone who doesn't already know what's going on.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a beginner to understand `(++) . (\f -> ...)`, either. At best, that would arise the question "why doesn't this trigger a type error?".

Comment: It would probably be easier to follow if you use `concatMap f` instead of `foldr ((++) . f) []`